# Possible to use stylelint for internal and inline stylesheets?

Tags: css, stylelint, csslint

I'm able to use stylelint for `.css` files according to their usage guide. Is there any way to use it for inline and internal stylesheets? I could write code to collect all those by parsing my HTML documents... is that my only option? Do I have to use another CSS linting tool like CSSLint?

Comment: Seems like there's a FAQ for style tags: http://stylelint.io/user-guide/faq/#how-do-i-lint-styles-within-style-tags. I would doubt that they have the ability to lint inline style attributes because, you know, you're not supposed to use those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the stylelint processor [stylelint-processor-html](https://github.com/ccbikai/stylelint-processor-html)

See also http://stylelint.io/user-guide/processors/ for a list of other stylelint processors.